# Applet on wordpress blog

Tags: java, wordpress, deployment, applet

I just finished making a Java applet and it works on my localhost server, however, I want to upload it to my blog on wordpress. How should I go about doing that?

I've never done it before, it's my first time, so help is greatly appreciated. Do I upload my .class files to wordpress, or do I upload them somewhere else and link them in my HTML file? If I do upload them to a different server, I'm not sure how to link to them. If anyone knows of a tutorial or is willing to tell me how to go about doing this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can upload applets to that site, or include `applet` elements, but if you can run scripts and hot-link to it elsewhere, it should not be a problem.  The script to use is the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).

> Do I upload my .class files to wordpress, ..

Don't upload loose class files.  Very soon all applet code will need to be digitally signed in order to not be automatically rejected by the Java Virtual Machine.  To be digitally signed, code must be in a Jar file.

> ..or do I upload them somewhere else and link them in my HTML file?

If you need to go with 'somewhere else', it should just be a matter of specifying the `codebase` to point to the site.  Here is the example from the [Using Applet Tag Attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#appletTagAttributes) of that document linked above.

```javascript
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'http://sample-url/Java2D',
                      code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet',
                      archive:'Java2Demo.jar',
                      width:710, height:540} ;
    var parameters = {fontSize:16, permissions:'sandbox'} ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

Note that I altered it slightly in the `code` attribute, because it irritates me to see Oracle itself perpetuating a myth that adding the file extension is a good idea.  The code attribute should be the **Fully Qualified Name** of a class, rather than the file name.

> If anyone knows of a tutorial..

I know a lot of good resources about applets, and I included links to them in the [Applet tag info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) here at SO.

---

All the best.  The (robust) *deployment* of a simple applet can be more tricky than the *development* of it - you have a steep learning curve ahead.